# How to change BorderColor of a selectable Panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, custom-controls, gdi+

I want to change all panel's BorderColor to Color.Lime:

```
foreach (Control G in GetAllControls (this))
{
    Panel p = sender as Panel;
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, p.DisplayRectangle, Color.Lime, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset);
}
```

It shows me this error:

> Severity Code Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061 'EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Graphics' and no accessible extension method 'Graphics' accepting a first argument of type 'EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is this a button's click event?  That EventArgs won't have a Graphics object.  You would have to do the painting in each Panel's Paint event instead.

Comment: Oh, well can you tell me the right one?

Comment: I already did that.

Comment: @LarsTech is there any other way to do it? cuz i have like 100+ panels and there has to be a easier way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a suggestion, use a Custom Control derived from Panel -if you need its features - or from Control, to have a lightweight Control - if you don't require any predefined behavior (except the base Control functionality, that is).

For example, a simple tweak of the Panel class that adds some properties that allow to define:

- a Color to assign to the Border
- the Size of the Border
- the Color of the Border when the Control is selected
- means to make the Panel *selectable*: it will change the Border Color when the Control is entered, you can set `TabStop = true` and Tab to *highlight* etc.

To make the Control selectable, some styles are modified when the `Selectable` property is set.
The Control calls [SetStyle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle) and sets `ControlStyles.Selectable`, `ControlStyles.UserMouse` and `ControlStyles.StandardClick` to `true` or `false`, then [UpdateStyles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.updatestyles), to force the new style (the Control retrieves the styles from the [CreateParams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.createparams) property), then [Invalidate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate) itself (this calls the `OnPaint` method, which in turn raises the Paint event) to draw the Border in the new state.

---

Add class named `PanelEx` to the Project, paste in what's in here (preserving the Namespace, of course), build the Project, find the new Control in the ToolBox and drop is on a Form.
If you want to replace all standard Panel Controls with this one, use the  search/replace functions of Visual Studio (<kbd>CTRL+H</kbd>) and replace  existing standard `Panel` Type objects (those that need the new behavior) with the `PanelEx` Type.

**NOTE - `x64` Projects:**
If the main Project needs to target `x64`, you can add a new Class Library Project that targets `AnyCPU` to the Solution. Add this Custom Control class (or any other Custom Control you have built, of course) to this Library. Also add a Reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Drawing` assemblies.
Rebuild the Solution and Visual Studio will add to the Toolbox all the Controls found in the library.
Nobody will complain when you then drop your Controls on a Form from the Toolbox.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[DesignerCategory("code")]
public class PanelEx : Panel
{
    private Color m_BorderColorSel = Color.Transparent;
    private Color m_BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
    private bool m_Selectable = false;
    private bool m_Selected = false;
    private int m_BorderSize = 1;

    public PanelEx() { }

    public Color BorderColor { get => m_BorderColor;
        set {
            if (value == m_BorderColor) return;
            m_BorderColor = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public int BorderSize {
        get => m_BorderSize;
        set {
            if (value == m_BorderSize) return;
            m_BorderSize = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public bool Selectable {
        get => m_Selectable;
        set {
            if (value == m_Selectable) return;
            m_Selectable = value;
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable | ControlStyles.UserMouse | ControlStyles.StandardClick, value);
            UpdateStyles();
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public Color BorderColorSelected {
        get => m_BorderColorSel;
        set {
            m_BorderColorSel = value;
            if (!Selectable || value == m_BorderColorSel) return;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Color penColor = m_Selectable && m_Selected ? m_BorderColorSel : m_BorderColor;
        int rectOffset = BorderSize / 2;
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(penColor, BorderSize)) {
            var rect = new Rectangle(rectOffset, rectOffset, ClientSize.Width - BorderSize, ClientSize.Height - BorderSize);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        OnEnter(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        OnLeave(e);
    }

    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnEnter(e);
        m_Selected = true;
        Invalidate();
    }
    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLeave(e);
        m_Selected = false;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: it always gives this error : ( https://www.linkpicture.com/q/rip_7.jpg

Comment: My project is 64 Bit

Comment: OMFGGG IT WORKEDDDDDDDDDDD!!! I changed 64 bit to any cpu and rebuild yeyyy thx man thx thx thx THX... I was literally going to paint every single panel :D you are a life saver ❤

Comment: So how am i supposed to add a "Class Library Project"? and change it to x64?
_Sorry if i am asking so many quesitons. i just don't want to do anything wrong._

Comment: I can create a class inside the "CustomControls" project. But when i paste the same thing it is showing me soooo many errors like

`'GreenPanel' does not contain a definition for 'Invalidate' and no accessible extension method 'Invalidate' accepting a first argument of type 'GreenPanel' could be found`

[Errors](https://ibb.co/q7Lp9ht)

Comment: When you add a Class Library, the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly (and others) are not added to the Project by default. You have to manually add the Reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Drawing`, then add the `using` directives in the classes that use these assemblies. Or press `ALT+Enter` on, e.g., `Panel` in `public class PanelEx : Panel` and on `Color` and Visual Studio will suggest the Assemblies References to add to the Project.

Comment: it wanted me to install "System.Windows.Forms.dll" so i did now there are none errors but when i rebuild i can't see the panel in toolbox.

Comment: i am ok with Any Cpu but i have another problem. i want the custom panel to do something. But when i click nothing happenes :(. Like i have to click twice how can i fix it?

Comment: If you want your Control to do *something*, you have to code for it. If it's something common to all Controls, you can override `OnMouseClick`. Otherwise, you can handle the MouseClick event in the Form. -- If there's something your code fails to do, then post a question about it.